# How to realize a gantt chart with Adobe Catalyst

Tags: flash, gantt-chart, flashcatalyst

I am not quite shure that its possible or even ment to be done with Catalyst, thats why I am asking if its possible. And when its possible how

I got a Illustrator File containing all Elements of a Gantt Chart like TaskItems, Milestones a Top bar showing the Calendar Week an so on. Shure its easy to implements a "fake" scroll function to move a little bit to the left or right. But is it possible to create again Chart similar to creating a "normal" DataList or even by somehow using the DataList ?

Or has the full animation to be implemented in Flash Builder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my today's knowledge goes with the current version of Flash Catalyst you have to go to FB in order to realise the Ganttchart.

Because FC can't do anything with user interaktion "data"